# Check if Mobile (.m) website exists Query Issue

Tags: c#, web, httpwebrequest, exists

I'm having trouble checking if a url exists.
I use the below for most checks - its the best method I have found and saves on a full web request but it does;nt allow for checks on address such as:

m.bbc.co.uk

Any mobile site for m., has no effect and breaks.

```
public static bool Does_URL_Exists(string str_url)
    {
        // using MyClient from linked post
        using (var client = new MyClient())
        {
            client.HeadOnly = true;
            // fine, no content downloaded
            try
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(str_url);
                string s1 = client.DownloadString(str_url);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
class MyClient : WebClient
{
    public bool HeadOnly { get; set; }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest req = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (HeadOnly && req.Method == "GET")
        {
            req.Method = "HEAD";
        }
        return req;
    }
}
```

Any clues on how I cam make this work. www.bbc.co.uk/m is no good either.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need load all string of link to client, only check status when connect to url is OK (200).

with url as: "http://www.bbc.co.uk/". i think mobile like of direct link is: "http://www.m.bbc.co.uk/"

Hope help to you